# Failed to load C:\xampp\htdocs\flash-forgepvtltd\storage\framework\cache\laravel-excel\laravel-excel-y.html as a DOM Document

Tags: php, excel, laravel

Exporting Excel xlsx file but given this error.

In Export Data , the data like 'POINTER THERMOMETER 0-600°C' . the main reason is `0-600°C` .
but how to resolve the data i dont know.
the data is direct from the db.
if anyone have an idea about this please help me out.

but how to resolve the data i dont know.
if anyone have an idea about this please help me out.[image]

Comment: Have you tried consulting the software vendor for your support options? See as well: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) /Edit: And there is duplicate material on the site already, you need to clarify how yours is different as we keep one question at a time, please see [help] for more guidance how to ask a question and the site works.

Comment: yes, this is duplicate quetion. But that question's answer not solved my problem.

Comment: That could be, therefore I guess your question misses an answer so far, but that is not a reason pre-se to ask it again. There is no guarantee that a question gets/has your answer in general. See also my previous comments' other remarks for more guidance.

Comment: And if it helps: See the answer about `&` , then take `°` as `&` in your case and apply the same fix. So technically spoken, could it be that the answer is not in there only on first sight? And then when reading the answers and understanding how they work, they could be an answer already for your HTML-ish DOMDocument targettting data?

Comment: 'POINTER THERMOMETER 0-600°C' this type messages comes from db how can changed in table structure layout in php laravel

Comment: Yes, it may originate some time in the past from db, but the error message shows it comes from an actual file, not the db directly. Perhaps double-check there is improvement already in understanding the error message in full or start to list the different level of understandings it allows for you?

Comment: And just seeing you're using blade templating. double-check your template renders with the ASCII subset of UTF-8. That could also already solve your problem as then the HTML is only with the portable character set.